# passing image from list(stateless) component to display(stateful) component --react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
//ImagePlayer component
class ImagePlayer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            image: [],
            selectedImage: '',
        }

        this.handleImageSelection = this.handleImageSelection.bind(this);
    }

    handleImageSelection(source){
        this.setState({ImageList : source})
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                    <Paper> 
                        {/* this is the larger div where I want to render the image clicked on the list */}
                        <ImageList handleImageSelection={this.handleImageSelection}/>
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                    <Paper>
                        <ImageList />
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}

//ImageList component
onst ImageList = (handleImageSelection) =>{

    handleImageSelection=(image)=>{
        console.log(image);
    }
    
   return(
   images.map((image, id) =>
        <List>
        <ListItem key={id} >
        <div>
          <ListItemAvatar>
                {<img src=      {require(`../assets/${image.name}.jpeg`)} alt="thumbnail" onClick={()=>handleImageSelection(require(`../assets/${image.name}.jpeg`))}/>}
          </ListItemAvatar>
          </div>
          <div >)
```

How to render the image from List component to Class component in React? My list component is list of images and that should appear enlarged in class component when I click on any image on the list.

I first defined the state: `this.state ={ imageSelected: ''}`
then, `setState` for the same.
Also passed `handleImageSelection` as a function in list component, but it says

> 'handleImageSelection' is not a function
>
> onClick={()=> props.handleImageSelection()} //errr: not a function

Comment: Please, show some logically complete code sample to figure out what may possibly cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your list and display component are wrapped by common parent, you may [lift](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) necessary state (e.g. chosen image `id`) as follows:

```js
const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const imageList = [
  {id:0, name: 'circle', imgSrc: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI1MCIgY3k9IjUwIiByPSI1MCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==`},
  {id:1, name: 'triangle', imgSrc: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNNTAsMCBMMTAwLDEwMCBMMCwxMDAgeiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==`},
  {id:2, name: 'square', imgSrc: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMCwwIGgxMDAgdjEwMCBoLTEwMCB6Ii8+PC9zdmc+`},
]      
      
const List = ({images, onSelect}) => (
      <ul>
        {
          images.map(({imgSrc, name, id}) => (
            <li key={id} onClick={() => onSelect(id)}>
              <img className="thumbnail" src={imgSrc} alt={name}/>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
)

class Display extends Component {
  render (){
    const {imgSrc,name} = this.props.image
    return (
      <img className="fullsize" src={imgSrc} alt={name} />
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    chosenImg: null
  }
  
  images = imageList
  
  onSelect = _id => this.setState({
    chosenImg: this.images.find(({id}) => id == _id)
  })
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <List images={this.images} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
        { this.state.chosenImg && <Display image={this.state.chosenImg} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  max-width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fullsize {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: in my case, one component that holds the list is functional component. Is that the reason, I am getting err? I have updated the initial post upon your request. Thanks for this snippet, I will have to check if I can reproduce or not.

Comment: Perhaps there is something to figure out in my code. Will let you know once it is working. Thanks,

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly now. I messed up on the render method earlier.